# wp-deploy environment setup: wp stderr: /usr/bin/env: wp: No such file or directory

Tags: wordpress, capistrano

I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Mixd/wp-deploy) to setup a Wordpress remote staging server. When I run the command: `bundle exec cap staging wp:setup:remote` it runs fine for a while until it reaches this step:

`INFO [27763386] Running /usr/bin/env wp core install --url='[server]' --title='[title]' --admin_user='[username]' --admin_password='[password]' --admin_email='[email]' as root@[server]`

This gives me the error

`(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as root@[server]: wp exit status: 127
wp stdout: Nothing written
wp stderr: /usr/bin/env: wp: No such file or directory`

Does anyone know what the problem could be here? I've followed the instructions from the wp-deploy github exactly and can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably logging on staging machine as a root. Try to use another user.
If you definitely want to setup wp under root user, you should edit lib/capistrano/tasks/wp.cap and add `--allow--root` in install command.

it should look something like this:

`execute :wp, "--allow-root core install --url='#{wp_siteurl}' --title='#{title}' --admin_user='#{user}' --admin_password='#{password}' --admin_email='#{email}'"`

**WARNING**: running wordpress under the root user is a terrible idea. :)

P.S. Also check if you have wp-cli on your staging server.